# How do I call this methods with a parameter in ObjC

Tags: objective-c, iphone

I'm quiet new in ObjC and app programming. All I want to do is fade in an image. For that I did this:

```
-(IBAction)changeImg:(id)sender{
    myImgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
    myImgView.alpha = 0;
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    myImgView.alpha = 1;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

That works quiet good. But now I want to put the fade function into an own method and I don't know how to call that method:

```
-(IBAction)changeImg:(id)sender{
    myImgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
    [myImgView fadeIn:self];
}

-(void) fadeIn:(UIImageView *) imgFade{
    imgFade.alpha = 0;
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    imgFade.alpha = 1;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

When I call the method like this I get a warning:"*'UIImageView' may not respond to '-fadeIn:'*"

Can anyone help me please?

---

Sorry but I don't get it to work.
The warning stays.
And when I do it like kuroutadori suggested:

```
...
self.alpha = 0;
...
```

I get an error:
"*request for member 'alpha' in something not a structure or union*"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are declaring `fadeIn:` on your current class (we would need more code to see which one it is) yet calling it on an `UIImageView` instance (in your case **myImgView**).

You should either declare it privately in your current class implementation file (as [Jonathan Grynspan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/265530/jonathan-grynspan) [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3459223/how-do-i-call-this-methods-with-a-parameter-in-objc/3459365#3459365)). Or if you're extensively using this animation, put it into UIImageView itself through a category:

```
@interface UIImageView (MyFade)

- (void) fadeIn;

@end
```

and then implement it with

```
@implementation UIImageView (MyFade)

- (void) fadeIn
{
    self.alpha = 0;
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    selfe.alpha = 1;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

Put `-changeImg:` after `-fadeIn:`. Better yet, declare your private methods in a category at the top of the file:

```
@interface MyClass (PrivateMethods)
- (void)fadeIn: (UIImageView *)imgFade;
@end
```

You don't need to pass `self` around like that--every method you call on the same object will have the same `self`.

Comment: hmmm I don't seem to get it. I did all the changes but the warning still appears.

Comment: Did you replace `MyClass` with the actual name of your class?

Answer (score 0):

That warning usually comes up because there is no written declaration in the the interface file or `.h` file.

I assume that fadeIn is in `myImgView` class, so why are you passing self? Just make it `[myImgView fadeIn];` and replace `imgFade` with `self`.

Code for source `.m`

```
@implementation MyClass
-(IBAction)changeImg:(id)sender{
    myImgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
    [myImgView fadeIn];
}

-(void) fadeIn{
    self.alpha = 0;
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    selfe.alpha = 1;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
@end
```

Add to your header `.h`

```
  - (void) fadeIn;
```

Or as someone said, put at the top of the source file `.m` before @implementation.

```
@interface MyClass ()
  - (void) fadeIn;
@end
```

To make it private

Answer (score 0):

You've got it backwards.

```
[self fadeIn:myImgView];
```